# WebSocket Django Проблема

Tags: python, django, websocket

Возникает проблема при использовании WebSocket'ов. При запуске сервера сокеты работают, всё хорошо, но через некоторое время (всегда по-разному) клиент подключается к сокетам, но ничего не может отправлять/получать (будто зависли).

Использую: daphne, channels, redis, asgi

Настройки supervisor:

```
[program:daphne]
command= /home/site/daphne_start.bash
directory=/home/site/chat/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr = true
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile = /home/site/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

Настройки daphne_start.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="daphne"                                 
DJANGODIR=/home/site/chat/            
SOCKFILE=/home/site/django_env/run/gunicorn.sock 
USER=ubuntu                                         
GROUP=ubuntu                                        
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=chat.settings      
DJANGO_ASGI_MODULE=chat.asgi             
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/site/django_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR


exec daphne ${DJANGO_ASGI_MODULE}:application -b 0.0.0.0  -p 8001
```

Код consumers.py

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = '%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Отправка ответа клиенту через api метод:

```
channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)('%s' % validated_data['recipient'], {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': data
                })
```

Не могу разобраться в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код приложения

Comment: @V-Mor дополнил вопрос, еще что-то нужно?

Comment: @dddd , в консоле есть ошибки? Может, на клиенте или в консоле самой джанги?

Comment: @Александр нету, всё чисто